# Does equipping the whole set gives any additional bonus?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently thought of buying a `Cain's Fate` set to level up faster. In the game and on Battle.Net website it says:

- (2) Set:

  - Attack Speed Increased by 2%
- (3) Set:

  - 10% Better Chance of Finding Magical Items
  - Increases Bonus Experience by 30%

Does equipping the whole set(4 items) give any more bonuses?

Comment: I would bet the answer is no, but I will make this just a comment since I am not completely sure having stopped playing Diablo III after completing it once on normal. But starting about the time of Burning Crusade in WoW Blizzard started to give all set boni at 4/5 items since this gives you more flexibility by allowing you to swap one of the set items out. They once commented on this being desirable in their opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the bonus is identified on the items, no. In your example, putting on four pieces of Cain's Fate would not give you an additional bonus over putting on three pieces.

If, for example, you picked up a set that had bonuses for 4 or 5 pieces, then these sets would give additional bonuses as detailed on the items for equipping more pieces of the set.